# Can a C++ compiler perform RVO for a const return value?

Tags: c++, return-value-optimization, nrvo

Let's say I have the function

```
#include <string>

std::string const foo()
{
    std::string s = "bar";
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::string t = foo();
}
```

Can a compiler perform (named) return-value optimization for `t`, even though the types of `s` and `t` are both different from the return type of `foo` due to the `const`-ness difference?

(If the answer is different for C++03 and C++11 then I'm definitely interested in knowing the C++03 answer.)

Comment: Why don't you include the results of your experiments with at least one compiler?

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Well, Visual C++ 2008 optimized it away, but I'm not sure if the standard actually allows it or not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no way for RVO optimization to break the promise of a `const`, so there's no problem: RVO can be performed.

---

However, *move semantics* is affected by the `const`. It effectively disables move semantics, that is, calls of a `T(T&&)` constructor or move assignment operator. So in general, don't use `const` on a return value.

Scott Meyers originally recommended `const` on return values, for more sane coding.

Then Andrei Alexandrescu, in his [Mojo article for DDJ](https://www.drdobbs.com/move-constructors/184403855), noted that henceforth, with move semantics, `const` on return values should better be banned, and Scott's earlier advice ignored.

---

Now I never bothered to learn the various specialized RVO acronyms, like NRVO and so on. And a main reason is that these *changed meaning* halfway through, originally having one meaning with some custom functionality in the g++ compiler. The terminology here is just a mess.

So, if my terminology's wrong and I should really have used some other acronym, then please feel free to correct! :-)

Comment: +1 good point regarding move semantics, although it does make me wonder: so what's wrong with disabling move semantics with a const return value? Isn't RVO (which completely avoids instantiating an object) still better than move (which needs to still instantiate an object and do maintenance work in order to perform the actual move)?

Comment: @Mehrdad: move semantics is under programmer control, and compiler has no say in it, while RVO is under compiler control, and programmer has almost no say in it. for example, the call might be an assignment `s = foo()` instead of an initialization. then the `const` prevents moving the function string result's buffer: it will most probably be copied, with possibly yet another buffer allocated.

Comment: Okay, but *if* I know RVO is happening, it will *never* (in practice) be slower than a move, right? So performance-wise, if you can ensure RVO, then returning `const` is better than returning mutable?

Comment: @Mehrdad: hm, i think, you'd better define "better". not everybody agreed with scott meyers' original advice *at the time*. different definitions of "better" involved. okay, i now see that you write "performance-wise". i fail to see how `const` could improve the performance, but, my advice is to **measure**.

Comment: Does RVO allow elision of *move* constructors as well, or does it only allow elision of copy constructors?

Comment: @Mehrdad: yes, C++11 treats *move* and *copy* by the same rules wrt. elision. it's specified by §12.8/31 "When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the copy/move constructor and/or destructor for the object have side effects. ..." I think you can take it from there. ;-)