# Can a C++ compiler perform RVO for a named const variable used for the return value?

Tags: c++, c++17, return-value-optimization, nrvo

This question is a slight variant on a related question [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14429988/115751).

In C++17 I have a local variable that I want to be const to demonstrate it is unmodified once created per Scott Meyers *Effective C++* item 3 recommendation to [use const whenever possible](http://blog.ycshao.com/2012/01/20/effective-c-item-3-use-const-whenever-possible-2/):

```
#include <string>

std::string foo()
{
    const std::string str = "bar";

    return str;
}

int main()
{
    std::string txt = foo();
}
```

Can a compiler perform (named) return-value optimization for `txt`, even though the type of `str` is different from the return type of `foo` due to the const-ness difference?

Comment: Semantically, `return str` creates an object that is a copy of `str`, so RVO is possible.    It is questionable whether NVRO can be performed, since the returned object needs to be distinct from `str`.     However, depending on what analysis the compiler performs if the function is in the same compilation unit as the caller, it could inline and then eliminate the function call entirely, and replace `std::string txt = foo()` with the notional equivalent of `std::string txt("bar")`.

Comment: IANALL but surely `const` must apply to the scope of the variable to guarantee `str` remains unmodified during the call of `foo()`. How does destruction work otherwise?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The named return value optimization is enabled by copy elision specified in C++17 in [[class.copy.elision]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.elision). The relevant part here is [[class.copy.elision]/1.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy#elision-1.1):

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the constructor selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the object have side effects. […]
>
> - in a `return` statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function parameter or a variable introduced by the exception-declaration of a handler ([except.handle])) with the same type **(ignoring cv-qualification)** as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the function call's return object
>
> […]

emphasis mine. Thus, compilers are allowed to perform the optimization here. And [a quick test](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%0Avolatile+int+copy+%3D+0%3B%0Avolatile+int+move+%3D+0%3B%0A%0Astruct+string%0A%7B%0A++++string(const+char*)+%7B%7D%0A++++string(const+string%26)+%7B+%2B%2Bcopy%3B+%7D%0A++++string(string%26%26)+%7B+%2B%2Bmove%3B+%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astring+foo()%0A%7B%0A++++const+string+str+%3D+%22bar%22%3B%0A%0A++++return+str%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++string+txt+%3D+foo()%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:39.447492443409025,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g91,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:31.39031506450982,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:29.162192492081147,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) would seem to verify that compilers will actually perform this optimization here…

Note that the `const` may be problematic nevertheless. If a compiler does not perform copy elision (it's only allowed, not guaranteed to happen here; even in C++17 since the expression in the `return` statement is not a prvalue), the `const` will generally prevent the object from being moved from instead (normally cannot move from `const` object)…

Answer (score 0):

Agree with [Michael Kenzel's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2064761/michael-kenzel) answer. But there are some peculiarities with compiler optimizations. If you look at a simple example without optimizations, you can see a feature of the msvc compiler - https://godbolt.org/z/b7z6n1YMf

Without optimizations, msvc will produce a copy of the object instead of NRVO.
This may be important in some cases.