# Unintuitive RVO of function returning non-copyable const value?

Tags: c++, c++17, copy-elision, return-value-optimization

Consider the following example code in C++ >=17:

```
struct A{
    A() = default;
    A(const A&) = delete;
};

const A f(){ return A{}; }

int main(){
    const A& a = f(); // OK
    // A& b = f();    // Error: cannot convert 'const A' to 'A&'
    const A c = f();  // OK: Copy elision
    A d = f();        // OK!?
}
```

The class `A` is non-copyable, but because of the [mandatory copy-elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), we can put the result of `f()` into variables. According to [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) in cppreference.com, the above behavior is perfectly legitimate, since it is specified that the `const` quantifier on the returning value is ignored when copy-elision happens.

However, this behavior seems very counterintuitive to me. Since `A` is non-copyable, I feel like there should be no way to turn `const A` into `A` (except perhaps when you have `A::A(const A&&)` constructor). Is this a well-thought decision, or is this considered a defect in language specification?

(I have encountered this problem when trying to implement my own type-erasure class. The whole purpose of me specifying `const` on the return value of function `f()` was to prevent the user from getting a non-`const` lvalue reference of the object, but this specification seems to open a hole.)

**Edit**: This example might show the counter-intuition more clearly: Let's consider a class `A` that is movable but not copyable.

```
struct A{
    A() = default;
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = default;
};

int main(){
    // C++14: move / C++17: copy elision
    A a = A{}; 

    // C++14: error (deleted copy constructor) / C++17: copy elision(!!)
    A b = static_cast<const A>(A{}); 
}
```

[This does not compile in C++ <=14, but compiles in C++ >=17.](https://godbolt.org/z/63re18EoG) In a common case where a class is movable but not copyable, `const` meant there were no means to get a non-const object out of it before C++14, but it doesn't anymore (as long as `const` is added to a prvalue).

Comment: I think 3 & 4 are copy initialisation (object is created in place and no copy/move is required) see (1) in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization  _"...First, if T is a class type and the initializer is a prvalue expression whose cv-unqualified type is the same class as T, the initializer expression itself, rather than a temporary materialized from it, is used..."_

Comment: Yes, I agree.
However, I wonder why they made the decision to ignore cv-qualification of the prvalue when they put it into c++17.

Comment: Well, cv-qualifiers on return-types aside from class/union types are ignored. And they don't make all that much sense where allowed either. This is just another nail in the coffin.

Comment: @Deduplicator Even when it's not a return value from a function, when you explicitly `static_cast` a non-copyable object into `const`, it is ignored by the compiler... (I added this as the second example)

Comment: I wonder if it's really necessary to preserve and force the constness of an r-value to the l-value constructed from it. I don't see any danger in that, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @MatG Let's say we want to make our own (mutable) string class, having a `char*` inside it. We will make it completely deep-const, i.e. modification to the content of char array is possible only when one has the non-const pointer. With some type-erasure on releasing the memory, we could make the class handle both cases where the class owns the internal array and where it doesn't (i.e. an existing C-string is provided externally and we want to read/modify it using the class). However, if we want to handle both cases where the external string is `const` and non-`const` using the same class,

Comment: @MatG (cont.) we are in trouble. One natural way is to `const_cast` away external `const char*`, and then make sure that every instance of the string class is always `const`. Because we have made the class completely deep-const, we are safe as long as we don't have non-const reference to the object. But being unable to preserve constness of r-value, it is not possible to guarantee that the user does not get an l-value of the object.

Comment: There's a similar question here, but the answer is incomplete: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429988/can-a-c-compiler-perform-rvo-for-a-const-return-value

Comment: @AtnNn In that question, we are dealing with a copyable object (`std::string`), and without RVO the compiler would generate a copy before C++14. Of course the compiler is free to elide the copy there, but it was important that a copy constructor *exists* to convert a `const` value to a non-`const` value. In C++17, it feels intuitive that a non-`const` prvalue could be used to initialize a non-`const` variable without copy constructor, but it doesn't feel intuitive that even a `const` prvalue could be used to initialize a non-`const` variable when the copy constructor is explicitly deleted.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a **breaking** change to reject such an initialization with a movable object, since prior versions of the language would produce a move there.  Making it depend on the *cv*-qualification of the variable would have been very subtle.

For a **copyable** object, the new behavior is actually a **subset** of the old: the copy from the `const A` return value to the `A` variable could have been elided, in which case they were just as much the same object as in C++17.

Meanwhile, const return values have been somewhat frowned upon since C++11, where `f(return_const())` lost the ability to **move** into a (by-value) parameter.

The C++17 treatment of prvalues (“mandatory copy elision” is a name that makes sense only historically) enables yet other cases, like the return of **non-movable** objects in this example: the function is thought to specify *how* to initialize the object it “returns”, rather than actually returning a finished object.  In choosing this model, it was generally considered more important to support **more** kinds of efficient code than to support existing idioms for preventing misuse.

Comment: Would C++14 produce a move on `const` prvalues of objects that define `A::A(A&&)`? I thought that was to be rejected because we don't have an appropriate move constructor (which is `A::A(const A&&)`).

Comment: @eivour: No, but it would *copy* it if allowed, and it would be allowed to elide that copy, which has much the same effect as the 17 rule.

Comment: @Daviis Herring I see. But I didn't see the point in also making `const` to non-`const` copy elision *mandatory* (i.e. without checking existence of copy constructor). Even if the *mandatory* copy elision happened only in non-`const` to non-`const`, `const` to `const`, or non-`const` to `const` case, the compiler would still be free to optimize `const` to non-`const` case when we have the copy constructor, and that would not break any existing code while getting all new usage cases covered.

Comment: (cont.) And it feels (to me) a lot more *consistent* that way, because we would preserve the `const`ness in the sense that we cannot get a non-`const` value/reference out of a `const` value/reference if we don't have a constructor for it.

Comment: @eivour: Eliding the copy would (equally) break your string class that relies on the copy to establish a writable buffer.

Comment: Even before C++14 the compiler *may or may not* elide the copy if you have a copy constructor, so I think making it mandatory wouldn't count as "breaking" a C++14 code.

Comment: @eivour: I didn’t mean C++17 would break it, but that your string class, if copyable, would fail to protect its external string even in C++14 (if the compiler happened to elide the copy).

Answer (score 0):

Elision is merging multiple objects into one.

```
struct Bob {};

Bob foo() {
  const Bob b;
  return b;
}

const Bob x = foo();
```

here, the objects `b`, `x` and the anonymous return value of `foo()` are elided into the same object.

This object varies in `const`ness depending on which declaration you use.  The C++ standards committee decided that this efficiency gain was more than worth the `const` appearing and disappearing.

Now, in this case, guaranteed elision doesn't hold, as `const Bob b` cannot be guaranteed elided.

```
const Bob bar() {
  return {};
}
Bob foo() {
  return bar();
}

const Bob x = foo();
```

here we have guaranteed elision, and all 3 (or 4 depending) objects become the same object.